# How to move caption of edges in automaton?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this code for drawing an automaton in LaTeX.

```
\begin{figure}[htpb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=5pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,semithick]
\node[initial,state] (q0)                    {$q_a$};
\node[state,accepting]         (q1) [right of=q0] {$q_b$};

\path (q0) edge [loop above]   node {a} (q0)
        edge   [bend left , below ]        node {b} (q1)
    (q1) edge [loop above] node {b} (q1)
        edge  [bend left , above]      node {a} (q0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Which gives me this automaton:

[image]

How can i move b on the middle path above the edge and the a below?

Comment: That changed nothing.

Comment: `\path (q0) edge [loop above]   node {a} (q0)
        edge   [bend left , above ]        node {b} (q1)
    (q1) edge [loop above] node {b} (q1)
        edge  [bend left , below]      node {a} (q0);` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the nodes `anchor` key.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=5pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,semithick]
\node[initial,state] (q0)                    {$q_a$};
\node[state,accepting]         (q1) [right of=q0] {$q_b$};

\path (q0) edge [loop above]   node {a} (q0)
        edge   [bend left , below ]        node [anchor=south] {b} (q1)
    (q1) edge [loop above] node {b} (q1)
        edge  [bend left , above]      node [anchor=north] {a} (q0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Less is more: remove the positioning information `above` and `below`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%
  [->,>=stealth',shorten >=5pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,semithick]
  \node[initial,state]   (q0)               {$q_a$};
  \node[state,accepting] (q1) [right of=q0] {$q_b$};
  \path (q0) edge [loop above] node {a} (q0)
             edge [bend left]  node {b} (q1)
        (q1) edge [loop above] node {b} (q1)
             edge [bend left]  node {a} (q0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you want to move the label to the other side of an edge, then add the keyword `swap` to the node.

```
        (q0) edge [bend left]  node[swap] {b} (q1)
```